# objDataReader is Null - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am quite new to ASP.NET and C#, so I still do not have much of an idea as to how things work. I basically get an error when I run my program and create a maintenance task. My code is shown right below:

```
private DataTable getMaintenance()
        {
            DataTable maintenance_dt = new DataTable();
            maintenance_dt.Columns.Add("maintenance_ID");
            maintenance_dt.Columns.Add("DAILY_MAINTENANCE");
            maintenance_dt.Columns.Add("ADMIN_COMMENT");
            string SQLstr = "SELECT MAINTENANCE_ID,DAILY_MAINTENANCE,ADMIN_COMMENT FROM " + maintenance_table + " where " + key + " like " + value + " order by MAINTENANCE_ID ";
            using (DataTableReader objDataReader = OS.OSFunctions.executeSQLQuery(SQLstr))
            {
                while (objDataReader.Read())
                {
                    DataRow mItem = maintenance_dt.NewRow();
                    mItem[0] = objDataReader["MAINTENANCE_ID"].ToString();
                    mItem[1] = objDataReader["DAILY_MAINTENANCE"].ToString();
                    if (objDataReader["ADMIN_COMMENT"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        mItem[2] = objDataReader["ADMIN_COMMENT"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mItem[2] = "";
                    }
                    maintenance_dt.Rows.Add(mItem);
                }
            }
            return maintenance_dt;
        }
```

The error I get from running this states

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. objDataReader was null

This occurs when I attempt to create a maintenance task. The code for that is also below right here:

```
protected void createMaintenance_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string SQLstr;

                if (txtMaintenanceName.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (maintenance_table == "ACTIVE_DAILYMAINTENANCE")
                    {
                        SQLstr = "SELECT TOP(1) MAINTENANCE_ID FROM ACTIVE_DAILYMAINTENANCE WHERE SCHEDULE_DATE = " + value + " ORDER BY MAINTENANCE_ID desc";
                        using (DataTableReader objDataReader = OS.OSFunctions.executeSQLQuery(SQLstr))
                        {
                            if (objDataReader.Read())
                            {
                                int id = Convert.ToInt32(objDataReader["Maintenance_ID"]) + 1;
                                SQLstr = "insert into " + maintenance_table + " (maintenance_id, DAILY_MAINTENANCE, " + key + ", ADMIN_COMMENT) values ('" + id + "',"
                                    + " '" + txtMaintenanceName.Text + "'," + value + ",'" + txtAdminMaintenanceComment.Text + "')";
                                OS.OSFunctions.executeSQLNonQuery(SQLstr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SQLstr = "insert into " + maintenance_table + "(DAILY_MAINTENANCE, " + key + ", ADMIN_COMMENT) values ('" + txtMaintenanceName.Text + "'," + value + ",'" + txtAdminMaintenanceComment.Text + "')";
                        OS.OSFunctions.executeSQLNonQuery(SQLstr);
                    }
        }
```

Again, it is the getMaintenance() method giving me the error. This also isn't all my code, I do call the getMaintenance() function sometime later in the code for CreateMaintenance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: CODE TRYING OUT DATA SET

```
private DataSet getMaintenance()
{
   DataSet maintenance_ds = new DataSet();
            string SQLstr= "SELECT MAINTENANCE_ID,DAILY_MAINTENANCE,ADMIN_COMMENT FROM " + maintenance_table + " where " + key + " like " + value + " order by MAINTENANCE_ID ";
            using(SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, connection);
                adapter.Fill(maintenance_ds);
                return maintenance_ds;
            }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your approach adding columns and values manually, consider to use `SqlDaataAdapter.Fill`: `var da = new SqlDataAdapter();da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, connection); da.Fill(dataset);`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. I get an error on this when I type in "connection". Does this mean that there isn't a valid SQL connection?

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation of `SqlDataAdapter` and it's [`Fill` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-datatable)). Of course you need a valid `SqlConnection` instance here.

Comment: Okay, I looked at the documentation and attempted it, however now it is giving me an "invalid object name" error when I do the adapter.Fill command. I have put the code above.

Answer (score 0):

So, you execute

```
DataTableReader objDataReader = OS.OSFunctions.executeSQLQuery(SQLstr)
```

in your `using`. `SQLstr` is

```
"SELECT MAINTENANCE_ID,DAILY_MAINTENANCE,ADMIN_COMMENT FROM " + maintenance_table + " where " + key + " like " + value + " order by MAINTENANCE_ID ";
```

You will need to use a debugger and jump to this line just before the error is thrown. First of all, you will need to find out what `maintenance_table`, `key` and `value` is. Try finding out what the generated query is and run it in your RDBMS, I think it will most likely return a `null` for some reason.

It is possible that you are just missing a wildcard character of `%` being wrapped around `value` if you have the intention to have a "contains" rather than an "equals" check.

Anyway, in order to detect what the error is you will need to find out what is being generated and why your query results in a `null`. Once you know what the problem is, you will also know what you need to fix, which largely simplifies the problem.

Since you do not use a parameterized query, I have to mention that if any of the dynamic values you concatenate to the query may come from untrusted sources, such as user input, then your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and you will need to protect your project against this potential exploit.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you can send the sql to a datatable, and the columns and the data table is created for you.

so, use this code to get/return a data table.

It not clear if  you "else" is to update a existing row, or insert a new one, but the code can look somthing like this:

```
  protected void createMaintenance_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime value = DateTime.Today;
        string maintenance_table = "";
        string SQLstr = "";
        string key = "";

        if (txtMaintenanceName.Text.Length > 0)
        {

            if (maintenance_table == "ACTIVE_DAILYMAINTENANCE")
            {
                // add new row
                int id = NextMaintID(value);
                string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM " + maintenance_table + " WHERE Maintenance_ID = 0";
                DataTable rstSched = MyRst(strSQL);
                DataRow MyNewRow = rstSched.NewRow();

                MyNewRow["maintenance_id"] = id;
                MyNewRow["DAILY_MAINTENANCE"] = txtMaintenanceName.Text;
                MyNewRow["ADMIN_COMMENT"] = txtAdminMaintenanceComment.Text;
                rstSched.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
                MyUpdate(rstSched, strSQL);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // update (or add to daily?????
            string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM " + maintenance_table + " WHERE Maintenance_ID = " + key;
            DataTable rstSched = MyRst(strSQL);
            DataRow MyRow = rstSched.Rows[0];
            MyRow["DAILY_MAINTENANCE"] = txtMaintenanceName.Text;
            MyRow["ADMIN_COMMENT"] = txtAdminMaintenanceComment.Text;
            MyUpdate(rstSched, strSQL);
        }
    }
```

So, I only need a few helper routines - (make them global in a static class - you can then use it everywhere - saves boatloads of code.

so these were used:

```
    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        // return data table based on sql
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }


    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        // return data table based on sql command (for parmaters)
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }

    void  MyUpdate(DataTable rstData, string strSQL)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

and of course this:

```
    int NextMaintID (DateTime value)
    {
        int result = 0;
        string SQLstr = @"SELECT TOP(1) MAINTENANCE_ID FROM ACTIVE_DAILYMAINTENANCE 
                        WHERE SCHEDULE_DATE = @scDate ORDER BY MAINTENANCE_ID desc";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(SQLstr);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@scDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = value;

        DataTable rstNextID = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        result = ((int)rstNextID.Rows[0]["Maintenance_ID"]) + 1;

        return result;

    }
```

So, how do you eat a elephant?
Answer: One bite at a time!!!

So, break out just a "few" helper routines that allows data operations against a data table object. That update command will work with edits, adds to rows, and even delete row method of a single row. All such updates can be thus be done with ONE simple update command.